# Find ulimit -a for other users

Tags: linux, monitoring, ulimit

Is anyone aware of a way to find the "ulimit -a" values for another user in Linux? I want user A to be able to check User B's ulimit values. Assumptions are the User A and User B are non-root users.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Limits are per-process, not per-user.

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying. I am trying to find the "max user processes" value for another user. When you run ulimit -a I get that value, along with other ulimit values, for the current user.

Comment: No, you get it for the current process.

Comment: `Since Linux 2.6.24, the resource limits of any process can be        inspected via /proc/[pid]/limits;`. However you are unlikely to have right to read another user files.

Answer (score 9):

Pancho's answer is correct, but sometimes you may get an error like this:

```
su - www-data -c "ulimit -n"
```

> No directory, logging in with HOME=/
>
> This account is currently not available.

You may specify a shell to overcome this:

```
su www-data --shell /bin/bash --command "ulimit -aH"
```

( `-aH` give you hard limit, `-aS` give you soft limit )

Comment: I need to check the limits for a user with no home dir so using it via shell saved me!

Comment: If password is asked then become first root with: 'sudo su -'.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest:

```
grep 'open files' /proc/$( pgrep -o <some-user> )/limits
```

For example:

```
grep 'open files' /proc/$( pgrep -o memcache )/limits
```

You need to realize that pgrep -o will match the oldest of the processes; which, I'd presume, is be the parent.

Answer (score 6):

If I am understanding correctly, you are wanting to achieve something like the following...

Assuming I am root and I would like to find out the soft limit information configured for the user fred, the following approach:

```
su - fred -c "ulimit -Sa"
```

will return the desired values.

Alternatively, if as per your question, you are not root, then you could use sudo and if desired inject the necessary password on execution as shown here

```
echo "freds password" | sudo -Siu fred ulimit \-Sa
```

Answer (score 0):

Select a process for user and identify your limits:

```bash
return-limits(){
  for process in $@; do
    process_pids=`pgrep $process`

    if [ -z $@ ]; then
      echo "[no $process running]"
    else
      for pid in $process_pids; do
        echo "[$process #$pid -- limits]"
        cat /proc/$pid/limits
      done
    fi
  done
}

return-limits mongod
```

Comment: Hi Diego - If you edit your post to prefix your code with four spaces on each line, it will format as code and be easier to read. Thanks!